# Change text color according to the text value in the column

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I was trying to change the text color according to the value inside the ***td***.
Here is what I mean.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td class="value-text">Hello there</td>
<tr>
</table>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script>  
$( ".value-text:contains('Hello')" ).css( "color", "red" );
</script>
```

This method works only if it's a div. But I need it to work on a ***td***.
Can anyone help, please?

Comment: Please include all relevant code. Do you have a div inside your td or what do you mean? Also to me this line makes no sense `it should be a div. But I need it to work on td. `

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen. Sorry My mistake, I have updated the question

Comment: Your code works fine I just tried it in a fiddle?

Comment: Yes it's working fine

Comment: Remember to close your `<tr>`. On the fourth line you have another opening `<tr>` where as it should be `</tr>`

Comment: Event with the tr not being closed your Code works. Check it here https://jsfiddle.net/azq52nhg/

Comment: Looks like I have made the mistake of not closing the tags. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You code work fine when done with modifications. You can refer to this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/qL96hmtc/

HTML code

```
<table>
<tr>
<td class="value-text">Hello there</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

JS code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( ".value-text:contains('Hello')" ).css( "color", "red" ); 
})
```